# How to serve a amp template

Tags: templates

I am in process of converting the present theme to AMP theme but it will take time to create as I have to learn the how to create the AMP theme

But till then I want to serve the only one template i.e single.php  as AMP.

I just want to confirm from the experts that if I detect the user request , if its coming from mobile then server different html  (AMP html)..

**Is it the okay  way ??..** 
**Will google consider it as AMP ??**

I am planning to use wp_is_mobile()  to detect the user request OR the following code

function w3_device(){
    $tablet_browser = 0;
    $mobile_browser = 0;

```
if (preg_match('/(tablet|ipad|playbook)|(android(?!.*(mobi|opera mini)))/i', strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']))) {
    $tablet_browser++;
}

if (preg_match('/(up.browser|up.link|mmp|symbian|smartphone|midp|wap|phone|android|iemobile)/i', strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']))) {
    $mobile_browser++;
}

if ((strpos(strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT']),'application/vnd.wap.xhtml+xml') > 0) or ((isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_WAP_PROFILE']) or isset($_SERVER['HTTP_PROFILE'])))) {
    $mobile_browser++;
}

$mobile_ua = strtolower(substr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 0, 4));
$mobile_agents = array(
    'w3c ','acs-','alav','alca','amoi','audi','avan','benq','bird','blac',
    'blaz','brew','cell','cldc','cmd-','dang','doco','eric','hipt','inno',
    'ipaq','java','jigs','kddi','keji','leno','lg-c','lg-d','lg-g','lge-',
    'maui','maxo','midp','mits','mmef','mobi','mot-','moto','mwbp','nec-',
    'newt','noki','palm','pana','pant','phil','play','port','prox',
    'qwap','sage','sams','sany','sch-','sec-','send','seri','sgh-','shar',
    'sie-','siem','smal','smar','sony','sph-','symb','t-mo','teli','tim-',
    'tosh','tsm-','upg1','upsi','vk-v','voda','wap-','wapa','wapi','wapp',
    'wapr','webc','winw','winw','xda ','xda-');

if (in_array($mobile_ua,$mobile_agents)) {
    $mobile_browser++;
}

if (strpos(strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']),'opera mini') > 0) {
    $mobile_browser++;
    //Check for tablets on opera mini alternative headers
    $stock_ua = strtolower(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_OPERAMINI_PHONE_UA'])?$_SERVER['HTTP_X_OPERAMINI_PHONE_UA']:(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_DEVICE_STOCK_UA'])?$_SERVER['HTTP_DEVICE_STOCK_UA']:''));
    if (preg_match('/(tablet|ipad|playbook)|(android(?!.*mobile))/i', $stock_ua)) {
      $tablet_browser++;
    }
}

$device = array($mobile_browser,$tablet_browser);
return $device;
```

}

Thanks in advance to all of you

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to have another look at the AMP documentation. You simply have to include the link to the AMP version of the article in the header of the post.

`<link rel="amphtml" href="http://www.example.com/post-slug/?amp" />`

After Google recognizes your posts have AMP versions it will automatically serve the AMP version for you.

Also, this is a great tool I have used in the past to help validate your AMP markup: https://validator.ampproject.org

Comment: thanks  a lot for the prompt help .. So the url for the amp verision is going to be different ...

Comment: Correct! For example, the WordPress AMP plugin converts your posts into `http://example.com/post-slug/amp`. I find the plugin too limiting so I AMP my own themes but you may have some success using it https://en-ca.wordpress.org/plugins/amp/

Comment: Also, poke around other AMP pages that are already live on the web. Like try an article from Wired. If you check the source it will have an `rel="amphtml"` link in the header.

Comment: thanks a lot for lot of  info ....       This seems like it is taking to take a while like it was learning while theme development.. :(

Comment: Agreed, it can definitely feel a bit daunting when you first dive in. IMO the documentation is not fleshed out enough.